# kvm - how to use a usb as storage

Tags: permissions, virtual-machine, kvm

I'm on Debian testing.

I'm trying to install a vm on a storage which is located on a ext4 formated usb stick. However I'm getting a permission error before the OS can be installed. I'm using Virtual Machine Manager:

```
Unable to complete install: 'Cannot access storage file '/media/user/mnt/generic.qcow2' (as uid:121, gid:131): Permission denied'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 88, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2288, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 461, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 396, in _create_guest
    self.domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3777, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: Cannot access storage file '/media/user/mnt/generic.qcow2' (as uid:121, gid:131): Permission denied
```

I mounted the usb using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /media/user/mnt  -o rw
```

I have also tried to `chmod 777` on the mount point while the usb was mounted as well as on the storage file itself (generic.qcow2).

Further I changed the owner of the mount point to libvirt-qemu (uid=121) however the error still persists.

How can I provide the appropriate permissions to be able to install the OS?

Comment: Have you change the ownership of generic.qcow2 to uid 121:gid 131?

Comment: please post the output of `ls -ld / /media /media/user /media/user/mnt /media/user/mnt/generic.qcow2`

Comment: @MatijaNalis I recently reinstalled my system and am now using Fedora. I haven't tried yet to do the same thing described in my question but will see that I can give it a go this weekend.... won't be apples to apples unfortunately...